# Restore Aurora DB from snapshot through Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-aurora

I'm looking to create a rollback job to restore an Aurora Postresql DB cluster on demand (part of a disaster recovery work which will run in an automation server).

The existing cluster is part of an [Aurora Global Database](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-global-database.html) which is provisioned to 2 AWS regions through Terraform.

*Note: Access to the DB is through a Route53 record which points directly to the writer endpoint of the cluster in the primary region.*

Global DB creation:

```
resource "aws_rds_global_cluster" "example-global" {
  count = var.primary ? 1 : 0 // only one region is the primary
  global_cluster_identifier = "global-db"
  engine = "aurora-postgresql"
  # etc...
}
```

Cluster (creates a DB only in the primary region):

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "example-cluster" {
  cluster_identifier = "example"
  engine = "aurora-postgresql"
  global_cluster_identifier = "global-db"

  depends_on = [aws_rds_global_cluster.example-global]
  # etc...
}
```

and 3 instances per region:

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "example-instance" {
  count = 3

  cluster_identifier = aws_rds_cluster.example-cluster.id
  engine = aws_rds_cluster.example-cluster.engine

  depends_on = [aws_rds_cluster.example-cluster]
  # etc...
}
```

The above works fine and deploys the resources. It creates a snapshot once a day (default). From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-restore-snapshot.html) (and other answers in SO) it's clear that there's no way to restore from snapshot to the same DB, so eventually the plan I was thinking is:

1. Create a new cluster with a secondary region (effectively create a **new** global database)
2. Use the said snapshot to populate a new instance in the primary region
3. Update a Route53 record to point to the endpoint of the new cluster
4. Delete the old clusters (from all regions) and the old global database

What I've tried so far is to actually create the DB (from a snapshot) using the AWS CLI. But what I don't really get is how to update the TF state to include the new resources and then use TF to destroy the old DB/cluster resources (ideally in the same step).

Also even better if there's a way to describe the above steps in Terraform [as in the example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/rds_cluster#global-cluster-restored-from-snapshot) rather than having to use a custom script to restore the DB and then manually update the TF state.

Any pointers or thoughts?